# canGoBack() is not working in my Second Activity

Tags: android, webview

I have created a second activity, i have a web view in that, so I used this code to go back from the website contents to the home website, but if I press the back button app is stop working , anyone can help me ?

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
                if (mWebView.canGoBack()) { 
                    mWebView.goBack();
                } else {
                    finish();
                }
                return true;
            }
        }
    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

here is the log

> 08-25 18:00:48.805 24025-24025/com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient
>   E/InputEventSender: Exception dispatching finished signal. 08-25
>   18:00:48.805 24025-24025/com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient
>   E/MessageQueue-JNI: Exception in MessageQueue callback:
>   handleReceiveCallback 08-25 18:00:48.806
>   24025-24025/com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient E/MessageQueue-JNI:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                              at
>   com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient.Manorama.onKeyDown(Manorama.java:38)
>                                                                                              at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2655)
>                                                                                              at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2755)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2380)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4558)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4514)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4192)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4063)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4249)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>                                                                                              at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4063)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4395)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2299)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1923)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1914)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2276)
>                                                                                              at
>   android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>                                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
>                                                                                              at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
>                                                                                              at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                              at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                              at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
>                                                                                              at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828) 08-25
>   18:00:48.808 24025-24025/com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                        Process: com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient, PID: 24025
>                                                                                        java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method
>   'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                            at
>   com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient.Manorama.onKeyDown(Manorama.java:38)
>                                                                                            at android.view.KeyEvent.dispatch(KeyEvent.java:2655)
>                                                                                            at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2755)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2380)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4558)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:4514)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4192)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4063)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4249)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>                                                                                            at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:4063)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:4036)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:4089)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4055)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:4225)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$ImeInputStage.onFinishedInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4395)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$PendingEvent.run(InputMethodManager.java:2299)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.invokeFinishedInputEventCallback(InputMethodManager.java:1923)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.finishedInputEvent(InputMethodManager.java:1914)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager$ImeInputEventSender.onInputEventFinished(InputMethodManager.java:2276)
>                                                                                            at
>   android.view.InputEventSender.dispatchInputEventFinished(InputEventSender.java:141)
>                                                                                            at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:148)
>                                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:151)
>                                                                                            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5706)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                            at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1033)
>                                                                                            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:828)

Comment: share your logs so people actually understand your problem

Comment: share logs, inital guess is your mWebView object is null causing it to crash? log will give exact error

Comment: I have added the log @amod gokhale

Comment: I have added the logs @howdoidothis

Comment: this may be help you to resolve my problem @AmodGokhale

Comment: @howdoidothis can you solve it now ?

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean android.webkit.WebView.canGoBack()' on a null object reference at com.example.jaisonjoseph.newsclient.Manorama.onKeyDown(Manorama.java:38) at

Comment: what is code at line number 38 in Manorama.java ?

Comment: Have you initialized mWebView??

Comment: Can you ad the full activity code?

Answer (score 0):

Your webview object is not initalized. get the webview Id and if it's !null then getback key pressed

```
@Override public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
            switch (keyCode) {
                case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK:
             WebView webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.myWebView);
            if(webView!=null){
                    if (mWebView.canGoBack()) { 
                        mWebView.goBack();
                    }
    } else {
                        finish();
                    }
                    return true;
                }
            }
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
```

Comment: Still problem is there@amod